# why 'this' about the class disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Today I want to try something different to handle a ReactNode variable that could be change with my

so I take it as an object, and it`s key is number, value is the ReactNode i want.

everything was ok;

but when I click the button and trigger the onCance error occured!
like this

### **TypeError: Cannot read property 'panelRef' of undefined**

but why? I had bind this in the constructor;
i dont know.
Here is part of my code

```
import React, { PureComponent, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button, Steps } from 'antd';
import { PopPanel } from '@alife/alimekits-pop-panel';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Shop, CheckedItem } from '../../interface/index';
import styles from './index.module.less';

const Step = Steps.Step;

interface Props {
}
interface State {
  currentStep: number;
}
class CopyConfiguration extends PureComponent<Props, State> {
  [x: string]: any;
  private panelRef;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 1,
    }
    this.onCancel = this.onCancel.bind(this);
    this.stepBack = this.stepBack.bind(this);
    this.stepPush = this.stepPush.bind(this);
    this.onOk = this.onOk.bind(this);
    this.beginCopy = this.beginCopy.bind(this);
    this.handleConfirmTextChange = this.handleConfirmTextChange.bind(this);
  }

  onCancel() {
    console.log(' this ', this, )
    this.panelRef.hide();
  }

  onOk() {

    this.panelRef.hide();
  }


  // 使用策略模式做不同step下的footer按钮
   footer: {
     [index: number]: ReactElement;
   } = {
     1: (
        <div className={styles.footerBar}>
         <Button onClick={this.onCancel}>取消</Button>
         <Button type="primary" onClick={this.stepPush} disabled={false}>
           下一步
         </Button>
       </div>
     ),
     2: (
       <div className={styles.footerBar}>
         <Button onClick={this.stepBack}>上一步</Button>
         <Button type="primary" onClick={this.beginCopy}>
           开始同步
         </Button>
       </div>
     ),
     3: (
       <div className={styles.footerBar}>
         <Button type="primary" onClick={this.onOk}>
           隐藏
         </Button>
       </div>
     )
   }

  render() {
    const { state, footer } = this;
    const { currentStep } = state;

    return (
      <PopPanel
        title="同步配置"
        destroyOnClose
        footer={footer[currentStep]}
        ref={ref => this.panelRef = ref}
      >
        123
      </PopPanel>
    )
  }
}


export default PopPanel.wrapper(CopyConfiguration, true);
```

someexplain: PopPanel like the Modal from antd; this are usefull when i click the button. so it was disappear on the time that in the handle function; when i definition the footer in render. everthin is ok. but i want to know why this change to undefined in the function.

Comment: You don't need to bind every function to `this` in your constructor. Remove all the `.bind(this)` references and see if your `onCancel` works.

Another step will be to call `this.onCancel()` in your constructor and see if your console logs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript will set value to footer property before the constructor call. So the footer uses original callbacks.

The simplest way to fix it is to replace footer property with renderFooter() method who returns the same data

Comment: 3qu ， I had use bael to see what happend, and see footer was declared before functions binding. and so ,that tine, onClick not bind yet. and your way is good.but my tutor suggest me use arrow function and say There is no performance difference between them, so . 3qu again